# Bernoullis in Parallel pipes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Im having trouble with a scenario where a flow  *splits into two parallel pipes*  and  *then rejoins*  before exiting the control volume

what makes this scenario difficult is the parallel pipes are of varying diameter

At the diffluence  Pipe A has a diameter 2D and Pipe 2 has a diameter of 1D 
by the time they reach  the confluence they have reversed diameter  now have  Pipe A has a dimeter of 1D and Pipe B  has a dimeter of 1D

[image]
Bernoullis

Start - assume a flow velocity 5ms static pressure SP 100

$Q_s=A1.V1$

$Q_s=3.5$

$Q_s=15$

$TP=SP+\frac{1}2mv^2$

$TP=100+\frac{1}25^2$

$TP=112.5$

**Stream a**

$QA=A1.V1=A2.V2$

$A1.V1 =A2.V2$

$2A.5ms = 1A.10ms$

$112.5=SP+\frac{1}2m10^2$

$SP=112.5-50$

$SP=62.5$

**Stream b**

$A1.V1 =A2.V2$

$1A.5ms^-1 = 2A.2.5ms^-1$

$112.5.5=SP+DP$

$SP=112.5-\frac{1}2m2.5^2$

$SP=112.5-3.125$

$SP=109.375$

**Q Check**

$Q_s=3.5$=15=1.5+2.5=QA+QB=1.2.5+1.10=3.5=Q_e$

**Head Loss** 
What we know

All elements of flow converging at WILL have the same head loss.
The flow will adjust automatically so that the head loss in each branch pipe WILL BE THE SAME

$Hl_A=Hl_B$

According to resistance  coefficient  tables  the divergent pipe has a K value of 0.46 and the convergent pipe has a K value  of 0.1

As these are Losses are proportional to – velocity of flow,  this suggests that the expansion pipe will decrease its flow (to decrease its losses) while the convergent pipe must increase its flow to maintain continuity 
This means that the flow rates have diverged not come together but we know that they must be the same at the exit of the control volume examined

Continuity also tells us that the total flow rate must be the same at all points in the pipe

$_=_1+_1 =a_2+b_2 =_$

$_._=_a. _a+_._=_._++_ _ =_.A_$

$_.3=_a.2+_.1=_.1++_2 =_.3$

So on total head/ stagnation value we will have the same value at the convergence as both paths have experienced the same head loss but Bernoullis  tells us that we have very different velocities and static pressures at this point .

My question is how at the confluence does this follow that we do not require the same value of pressure and velocity at the confluence  for both streams?

If this can occur we must then have a mechanism to achieve the expected uniform velocity and pressure (Not considering head losses) at the exit 
 $_.3 =_.3$

What would this mechanism be ?

Comment: Did you mean diameters, or did you mean areas?

Comment: Hi @ChesterMiller Yes it is most like square ducting so area would probably be more appropriate

Comment: Let's see your two Bernoulli equations for the two parallel ducts.

Comment: Bernoullis 

Start - assume a flow velocity 5ms static pressure SP 100

$Q_s=A1.V1$

$Q_s=3.5$

$Q_s=15$

$TP=SP+\frac{1}2mv^2$

$TP=100+\frac{1}25^2$

$TP=112.5$


**Stream a** 

$QA=A1.V1=A2.V2$

$A1.V1 =A2.V2$

$2A.5ms = 1A.10ms$

$112.5=SP+\frac{1}2m10^2$

$SP=112.5-50$

$SP=62.5

**Stream b**

$A1.V1 =A2.V2$

$1A.5ms^-1 = 2A.2.5ms^-1$

$112.5.5=SP+DP$

$SP=112.5-\frac{1}2m2.5^2$

$SP=112.5-3.125$

$SP=109.375

**Q Check**

$Q_s=3.5$=15=1.5+2.5=QA+QB=1.2.5+1.10=3.5=Q_e$

Comment: Hi @chestermiller I have added in the breakdown

Comment: @chestermiller you'll note ive done this for inviscid flow only'. as I said if we were to add head loss my thinking is that the situation would be further apart not closer.  I should add that I am also aware of streamwise gradients from the confluence to the exit. Favourable for the slow flow 109.37-100 and Unfavourable for the fast 62.5-100 is that  the only mechanism(with viscosity) to bring the adjacent streamlines back together ? or is there something else that prevents them from developing different Bernoulli conditions  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out what you did, so here is my analysis, without the resistance.  Let:

Q = Total volume flow rate

$Q_a$ = Volume flow rate into converging pipe

$Q_b$ = Volume flow rate into diverging pipe

$p_1a$ = static pressure just after entrance to a

$p_2a$ = static pressure just before exit from a

$p_1b$ = static pressure just after entrance to a

$p_2b$ = static pressure just before exit from a

$T_1$ = "total pressure" in channel leading up to diffluence

$T_2$ = "total pressure" in channel after diffluence

$A_{a1}$ = cross sectional area of converging pipe at inlet

$A_{a2}$ = cross sectional area of converging pipe at outlet

$A_{b1}$ = cross sectional area of diverging pipe at inlet

$A_{b2}$ = cross sectional area of diverging pipe at outlet

**CASE OF NO FRICTIONAL LOSS**

Bernoulli equations relevant to pipe a:
$$T_1=p_1+\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a1})^2}{2}$$
$$p_1+\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a1})^2}{2}=p_2+\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a2})^2}{2}$$
$$p_2+\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a2})^2}{2}=T_2$$
Adding these three equations together gives $$T_1=T_2$$
Thus, for the case without friction, energy is conserved and the "total pressure" after the split section is equal to the "total pressure" before the split section.  This is irrespective of how the flow splits between the two sections.  The Bernoulli equations for pipe b will give the same result.  Also, the convergence and divergence in the channels doesn't matter, as long as the final outlet pipe has the same cross sectional area as the initial inlet pipe.

**CASE WITH FRICTIONAL EFFECTS INCLUDED**

Bernoulli equations relevant to pipe a:
$$T_1=p_1+\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a1})^2}{2}$$
$$p_1+\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a1})^2}{2}=p_2+\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a2})^2}{2}+k_a\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a1})^2}{2}$$
$$p_2+\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a2})^2}{2}=T_2$$
Adding these three equations together gives $$T_1=T_2+k_a\rho \frac{(Q_a/A_{a1})^2}{2}\tag{1}$$
Similarly, for channel b:$$T_1=T_2+k_b\rho \frac{(Q_b/A_{b1})^2}{2}\tag{2}$$

Thus, for the case with friction, mechanical energy is not conserved and the "total pressure" after the split section is not equal to the "total pressure" before the split section. Moreover, the split between the two channels is relevant.

Mass balance equation:
$$Q_a+Q_b=Q\tag{3}$$

Eqns. 1-3 provide three algebraic equations in the three unknowns $(T_1-T_2)$, $Q_a$, and $Q_b$.

Comment: hi @chestermiller yes that all makes sense with the literature  , but only if p2a does not equal p2b is that your expectation in fact no matter how the flow is split I I can't see any way it can (but it does normalise downstream)

Comment: That's correct.  The fluid flow converging from the big pipe into the entrance of pipe a (and the corresponding pressure change) is different from the fluid flow and pressure change from the big pipe into the entrance of pipe b.  In the case of pipe a, the flow is slowing down as it approaches the entrance, and, in the case of pipe b, the flow is speeding up as it approaches the entrance.

Comment: The flow that enters pipe a from the upstream conduit 1 slows down  in the immediate vicinity of the entrance to pipe a, with an accompanying increase in pressure.  Once inside pipe a, the flow speeds up as it converges toward the exit, with an accompanying decrease in pressure (to a value lower then in either conduit 1 or conduit 2).  Once the flow exits pipe a, it slows down to the velocity in conduit 2, with an accompanying increase in pressure, back up to the original value in conduit 1.  So the for the flow through a, the pressure first increases, then decreases, then increases again.

Comment: Of course, the discussion in my previous comment applies specifically to the case without friction.

Comment: Hi @chestermiller thanks for your explanation , I am interested in why the fluid slows down before it enters pipe a ( and vice versa pipe b)  intuitively I know this to be the case but I would love to put a name to the force . Is it due to the orthogonal area presented to the flow by the convergent pipe causes a force impulse . Why I wonder is again this suggests that the  Q would deviate to pipe b in an inviscid flow (as you stated) but the k values and head loss suggest that in a viscid flow the Q would deviate to pipe a ... This causes me much confusement

Comment: For the inviscid flow, the flow splits evenly between pipes a and b.  By symmetry, half the flow goes to a and half to b.  To understand what's happening at the entrance to the two pipes, it is easier to focus on pipe b.  The velocity in pipe b is higher than in conduit 1.  So the streamlines for  the flow to pipe b have to be converging toward the entrance to pipe b.  It's kind of like a funnel.  This convergence occurs mainly  in the region close to the entrance.  The flow convergence causes the fluid  velocity to increase and the pressure to decrease.  The opposite thing happens for pipe a.

Comment: Hi @chestermiller thanks for all your correspondence.

Comment: hi @chestermiller I have been thinking about the above question and have a further query . In the above example we have two different Bernoulli scenarios in each of our pipes at the confluence we will have a differential in static pressures (a pressure gradient perpendicular to the flow) between the two streamlines how does this gradient resolve itself ? What area of fluid mechanics studies this ?

Comment: If you want to solve for the actual detailed fluid velocity profiles and pressure profiles throughout the region of flow, you need to solve the Euler equations (for an inviscid fluid), or the Navier Stokes equations for a viscous fluid (assuming turbulence is not present).  For turbulent flow, additional approximations need to be made to describe the behavior.  Most computational fluid dynamics (CFD) software packages will handle calculations such as these.